# How to check all checkboxes in an Angular reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular form that shows a list of checkboxes:

```
<tbody formArrayName="approvedInvoices"
  *ngFor="let approvedInvoice of approvedInvoices; let i = index">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" 
          [formControlName]="i" id="{{i}}">
    </td>
    <td style="padding-top: 18px">
      Invoice Number {{approvedInvoice.invoiceNumber}}
    </td>
</tbody>
```

I create the form in my ngInit() :

```
approvedInvoices: ApprovedInvoice[];

this.controls = this.approvedInvoices.map(c => new FormControl(false));
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    approvedInvoices: new FormArray(this.controls)
  });
```

And this is my model:

```
export class ApprovedInvoice {
    invoiceNumber: string;
}
```

This works well, but my problem is that I don't know how to do a 'select all' .  I can get the list of invoices that are checked like this:

```
selectedInvoices() {
  return this.form.value.approvedInvoices
    .map((v, i) => v ? this.approvedInvoices[i] : null)
    .filter(v => v !== null);
}
```

But I don't know how to check all the boxes.

So far I have this:

```
selectAll() {
  for (var _i = 0; _i < this.form.value.approvedInvoices.length; _i++) {
    this.form.value.approvedInvoices[_i] = true;
  }
```

Which marks all the invoices as selected, however the checkbox input does not change (ie, it's not ticked

Comment: this link might help. https://plnkr.co/edit/XwxR0inmaZr8ieT4SlOr?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setValue method to set the value of individual form Controls in the formArray

```
selectAll(){
    this.form.get('approvedInvoices').controls.map(control=>{
      control.setValue(true);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  selectAll(): void {

  this.selectAllCheckbox = !this.selectAllCheckbox;

  if (this.selectAllCheckbox) {
      this.services.controls.map(control => control.setValue(true));
    } else {
      this.services.controls.map(control => control.setValue(false));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.